# Why does hackers use privilege escalation via impersonation token instead of simpler method

Tags: token

To get SYSTEM permission on a compromised system, attackers usually use a method to gain privileges via **named pipes with impersonation token**.

Even if, at this moment, I don't fully understand the concept above, I'm wondering why attackers do not use simply a rogue **service** that will launch a malicious program with SYSTEM rights ? Why do they need to create a named pipe and use an impersonation token?

Thanks !

Comment: there are many ways to escalate privileges - you only describe one way ... can you cite your source for hackers "usually" using this one particular method?

Comment: For example, the "getsystem" command of Meterpreter uses Named Pipe Impersonation by default. Creating a simple service to get SYSTEM rights seems to be simplier than it.

Comment: 'Why attackers don't simply use a rogue service' - you are assuming the attacker can just drop a rogue service and has the ability to start it with system privileges. I think this is a little simplistic.

Comment: Using named pipe with impersonation token to get SYSTEM privileges requieres that the attacker has administrator rights. The same requirement is necessary to create a service.  So I presume that the attacker has administrator rights and need to run a process as SYSTEM.

Comment: You don't need to be admin for `getsystem` to work. Let's set aside for the moment that `getsystem`  constitutes 'usually' for all hackers, and let me ask how you are imaging an admin might simply create a service that ''gets' SYSTEM privs? I think you might have some underlying assumptions in this whole thing that will make it difficult to answer your question as asked.

Comment: Ok, I think it's all about permissions ! Creating a named pipe does not requiere to have administrator rights, but creating a service does. That why I was unable to understand why they often use that first method instead of creating a service to have SYSTEM rights.